# ScrollView will not make page scroll

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollview

Can anybody tell me why this ScrollView is not working? I checked the other answers for this question and it hasn't solved my problem. It has just one child. It has a closing bracket. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#89abe3"
    tools:context=".GardaLoginActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#89abe3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Smart Neighborhood Watch"
        android:id="@+id/Logo"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:textColor="#ffdd00"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblGardaEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtGardaEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <requestFocus />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblGardaPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtGardaPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColorHint="#cccccc"
            android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGardaLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:background="#66c2ff"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="0.30" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGardaRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Not a member? Register"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you change android:layout_height="wrap_content" for RelativeLayout ??

Comment: @Cian see my answer below.

Comment: I tried your code. Scrollview does work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Important Note :**

> According to Android guidelines, android:layout_height attribute of
>   the first (and only) ScrollView children should always be
>   "wrap_content". You will get a Lint warning if you use match_parent

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
```

with this code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that i wrote this as an awnser as I can't comment on questions.
If your layout is bigger than your screen the scrollview will work.

And One more thing Child layout of `ScrollView's` height `wrap_content`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#89abe3"
        tools:context=".GardaLoginActivity" >

     <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="#89abe3">
           //Your Code
     </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Sorry. This did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

just Change your child Relative layout to

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="#89abe3">
```

as the relative layouts `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` attribute is using whole screen there is no room for ScrollView to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#89abe3"
    tools:context=".GardaLoginActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#89abe3"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Smart Neighborhood Watch"
            android:textColor="#ffdd00"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblGardaEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtGardaEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <requestFocus />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblGardaPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtGardaPassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGardaLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.30"
                android:background="#66c2ff"

                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewGardaRegister"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="Not a member? Register"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout8"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout9"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout10"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout11"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout12"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout13"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout14"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout16"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout15"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc" />
        </LinearLayout>
           <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout17"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout16"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Minimum 7 characters"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have checked your code. It's working perfectly even with scroll.
Do you have any other doubt?